# Google adwords keywords combinations (does it make a difference)

Tags: google-ads

I am wondering if Google Adwords treats keyword combinations listed below differently?

**Option A:**

[image]

**Option B** (combination of the above keywords) **:**

[image]

I hope anyone can answer me...

Comment: Can you tell us what those words translate to?   It is hard for us English speakers to understand this question with untranslated keywords.   I think they keywords don't matter much to this question.  I think you are asking about the `[ ] +` syntax.

Comment: Well I am asking about syntax as you said it but if you need the info: `+najstnik == +teenager` and `[psihološka pomoč] == [psychological help]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They do.

Since, both the options represent different user intents.

**In option A**, there are two keywords -

1. Teenager
2. Psychological Help

So, I could have two pages no my site, one on life of a teenager which is optimized for the first keyword. The other on the kind of Psychological Help we have to offer.

Notice, the intent is a bit more generic in this case, since we have taken the phrase and split it into two parts.

Now, lets take **Option B**.

Here, the phrase is Psychological Help +Teenager (can be for, can be towards, etc). The user intent is very specific. What Psychological Help is required for a Teenager.

The search volumes in this would be lesser, but I'd wager you would get better conversion rates due to the higher intent.

To answer your question about Google Adwords, yes it does treat these combinations differently.

In one, you are using a Broad Match Modifier (BMM). In the other you are using an Exact match with a BMM.

As someone who runs an agency based on Adwords, an easier approach would be to go with the Option B, and every week keep checking the Search Term Report for discovering the exact search patterns that users are querying on Google. Then keep adding these as phrase matches ("") in your campaign.

**TL;DR** - Go with Option B.

Comment: To add to this, you can also go through the Adwords Keyword Match types support article - https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/2497836?hl=en

Answer (score 1):

I would assume they do since you are talking about two different target keywords.

Teenager

Psychological Help + Teenager

are two different searches and are likely to have two completely different costs associated with them. Generally the more specific the keyword is the cheaper the buy will be and the likelihood that you are matching what a user is searching for is greater.

Comment: Is there any background on this?